# How to digitally sign the installation files of the desktop bridge app?

Tags: uwp, digital-signature, desktop-bridge

This problem may not be as simple as the title says, because for some reason, I am not authorized to have a certificate, and I can only give the program (not the code) to another person for digitally sign. I'll elaborate on the following.

What I already know is that after I upload the app to MS store, Ms store will automatically sign my app, but it seems that it will only sign the msixbundle file. because in this path: `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\[AppName]_[AppVersion]_neutral__[PackageID]`, I can see my DLL files and exe files - but these files are not signed, unless the DLL has been signed before uploading the app to the store, for example, Newtonsoft.Json.dll in the directory is signed, but my own [appname].exe file is not signed.

So, the question is: how can someone else sign my desktop bridge app installation files using signtool.exe **without having my code**?

Maybe this can't be achieved, but please tell me the solution, thank you.

Comment: They do not need the code. But they need the individual files. They can sign them and build the bundle out of them.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Thanks for reply, but what do you mean by independent files? What should I do, and how do they build the bundle? Any links?

Comment: The same way as you build the bundle?

Comment: Nope, I usually use vs2019 directly to generate msixbundle files that can be uploaded to the store.

Comment: Then you can provide them with a script that [builds the package with `makeapp.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/package/create-app-package-with-makeappx-tool). Or have them give you the signed binaries and build the package yourself the same way.

Comment: Thank you very much for your patience. I think this should be the right way. But when I try to use makeappx to create msixbundle file, I find those complex commands too difficult for me. Is there a more easily way to create msixbundle file according to the existing package.appxmanifest file? Or it would be great if you could give me with a few simple commands to learn :)

Comment: That's quite broad question. Anyway, consider asking a follow up question (like *"How to convert Visual Studio for UWP app to makeapp command-line"*). Post a link here is you do.

Comment: Thanks again! I'll do it.