# How to use makeappx to create msixbundle files that can be uploaded to the store according to the appxmanifest file?

Tags: digital-signature, desktop-bridge, makeappx

For some reason(about the digital signature of the desktop bridge app, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61832009/how-to-digitally-sign-the-installation-files-of-the-desktop-bridge-app)), I can't use visual studio to package my project. Makeappx seems to be able to do this, but those commands are too complex for me. Is there an easier way to achieve this?

Or to put it another way, how can I directly refer to the EXE file (which I can sign) rather than just the project in the application package project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Visual Studio is too complicated I recommend you get the [free Express edition from Advanced Installer.](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/express-edition.html)

In the link include you can find a video that shows how to build an MSIX package (for bundle just change the radio button option from Builds page).

[image]

Additional info -

[Publishing an MSIX package in the MS store.](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/msix-publish-microsoft-store.html)

*Disclaimer: I work on the team building Advanced Installer.*

Comment: I've used the advanced installer, which is really easy to use and perfect. But it doesn't seem to be able to generate msixbundles to upload to the windows store. On this question, I have got the answer I wanted [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/27432/how-to-digitally-sign-the-installation-files-of-th.html).

Comment: Glad to hear you got it working Victor. Regarding the bundle generation from Advanced Installer, have you tried the options from the screenshot above?

Regarding the entire process of publishing an app to the store, we have a detailed article here: https://www.advancedinstaller.com/msix-publish-microsoft-store.html

Comment: I'm so sorry, I forgot to reply.
Because of network problems, I have not seen the screenshot above, which is very useful. At the same time, thank you very much for your answer, I hope your answer can help more people!